# Is the Kubernetes version and AKS distributed Kubernetes version the same?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

Is Kubernetes version and AKS versions are refereing the same versioning ?

For example, Is AKS version 1.18.14 refers to the same of Kubernetes version 1.18.14?

Because Istio 1.7 version is support Kubernetes 1.18.x only. so need to know if we upgrade AKS to 1.19.x, whether it will be compatible with istio 1.7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see AKS supported versions -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions

the following link shows that istio 1.7 is not supported for kubernetes 1.19 -

https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes version is equal to the AKS version of Kubernetes.

You can refer to the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions).

This mean that if isto-v1.7 is supported only on K8S v1.18.x, it will **NOT** work on AKS v1.19.x